# Pair and add corresponding elements in multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a json data like :

```
[
  [
    "2020-05-07T16:30:00.000+0530",
    1,
    29,
    693,
    0,
    7,
    3663,
    7413
  ],
  [
    "2020-05-07T15:30:00.000+0530",
    0,
    16,
    996,
    3,
    13,
    4452,
    10106
  ]
]
```

Using JQ, I want to add the corresponding elements of the both array and result a new array. In case of date string the value from one of the array will be fine. The Expected output is

```
[
        "2020-05-07T16:30:00.000+0530",
        1,
        45,
        1689,
        3,
        20,
        8115,
        17519
      ]
```

Please can u suggest the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pair corresponding elements using `transpose`, and create a new array with sums of them.

```
transpose | [.[0][0]] + map(add)[1:]
```

<sup>[demo at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/X1NbZxbeoH)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for the same output. I will look more on Transpose